# SQL Reorganize table for SSRS display

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a set of data as such:

```
LocaId  Location  StaffId
1       Main St   1
2       South Ave 1
3       South Ave 2
4       2nd St    1
5       2nd St    2
6       Lewis Ave 1
```

I want to display the data for an SSRS report like with Location used in the header.

```
          John       Mark
Location  Main St    South Ave
Location  South Ave  22nd St
Location  22nd St    Null
Location  Lewis Ave  Null
```

But with the following Code:

```
SELECT 'Location',
(CASE WHEN l.StaffId = 1 THEN l.Location ELSE NULL END) AS 'John',
(CASE WHEN l.StaffId = 2 THEN l.Location ELSE NULL END) AS 'Mark'
FROM Location l
```

I get the following results.    It seems like it would be easy to display the data correctly but I don't get the result I need to display on the report.

```
         John        Mark
-------- ----------- ---------
Location Main St     NULL
Location South Ave   NULL
Location 22nd St     NULL
Location Lewis Ave   NULL
Location NULL        Main St
Location NULL        South Ave
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an aggregate function :

```
SELECT l.location,
MAX(CASE WHEN l.StaffId = 1 THEN l.Location ELSE NULL END) AS 'John',
MAX(CASE WHEN l.StaffId = 2 THEN l.Location ELSE NULL END) AS 'Mark'
FROM Location l
GROUP BY l.location
```

Comment: Thank you, I always thought that Aggregate was for numbers and not text data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `null` values to appear at the bottom of the list, then you can use:

```
SELECT 'Location',
  MAX(CASE WHEN l.StaffId = 1 THEN l.Location ELSE NULL END) AS 'John',
  MAX(CASE WHEN l.StaffId = 2 THEN l.Location ELSE NULL END) AS 'Mark'
FROM
(
  select StaffId, location,
    row_number() over(partition by StaffId order by locaid) rn
  from Location
) l
GROUP BY rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e39ce/3)

You can also use the `PIVOT` function to transform the data:

```
select 'Location',
  [1] as 'John',
  [2] as 'Mark'
from
(
  select staffid, location, 
    row_number() over(partition by StaffId order by locaid) rn
  from location
) src
pivot
(
  max(location)
  for staffid in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e39ce/8)

The result is:

```
| COLUMN_0 |      JOHN |      MARK |
------------------------------------
| Location |   Main St | South Ave |
| Location | South Ave |    2nd St |
| Location |    2nd St |    (null) |
| Location | Lewis Ave |    (null) |
```